# Cant find a combobox control in edittemplate in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to find this control in the Gridview's edititemtemplate section.

```
  <EditItemTemplate>
                    <ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID="GridviewCategoryComboBox1"  AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" AutoCompleteMode="Suggest" DataSourceID="GridViewCategorySqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id" MaxLength="0" Style="display: inline;">
        <asp:ListItem>Select Category</asp:ListItem>
    </ajaxToolkit:ComboBox>
```

Here is the event handler where I try to fetch the control that is in the edititem template.

```
  protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs 

e)
        {
            GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            int id = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Value;

            ComboBox ddl = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("GridviewCategoryComboBox1") as ComboBox;
}
```

It returns null, no matter who I try to find it.

I also tried other variations such as this:

```
ComboBox ddl = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("GridviewCategoryComboBox1") as ComboBox;
```

Comment: You could try this recipe https://blog.codinghorror.com/recursive-pagefindcontrol/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `RowDataBound` event for this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0) {
            ComboBox ddl = (ComboBox)e.Row.FindControl("GridviewCategoryComboBox1");
        }
    }
}
```

Because it is likely that you have other code in the `RowDataBound` event, then this allows you to centralize all your code in that event and avoid duplicate code.